# Unable to setup Grunt mac

Tags: gruntjs

I have installed grunt on my system using `npm install`, and also have installed the command-line-interface for it, but when I try to run `grunt` it throws the following error,
`Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile.` What is missing in here? There is no documentation for the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first route should be to use a search engine for things like this rather than as a question.  Also, you should include what you tried for debugging as part of your question.

As for the answer...like the error says, `grunt` can't find your `Gruntfile.js`.

The grunt website has a [getting started](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) page that explains the basics of the tool and then another [entire page dedicated strictly to the Gruntfile](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile).

A quick search also showed that this question and variants of it have been answered many times on this site and on other pages around the internet.

But as a summary: if you didn't create a Gruntfile in your project directory, this is the error you get.  The solution is to create a Gruntfile as the grunt docs describe.

Comment: I am sorry. I guess I didn't try properly.